# OpenLDAP modify member is not allowed

Tags: freebsd, ldap, openldap

I am Struggeling with my [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDAP) attributes.

I already created a few test users and groups, but I am unable to add users to the groups.

```
#!DATE 2014-05-22T11:48:16.324
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 65 - attribute 'member' not allowed]
dn: cn=test,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org
changetype: modify
add: member
member: cn=User Name,ou=users,dc=example,dc=org
```

The user group is just a simple PosixGroup:

```
dn: cn=test,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org
changetype: add
gidNumber: 1234
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
cn: test
```

Nothing else. This is (I think the relevant) debug output:

```
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_required entry (cn=test,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org), objectClass "posixGroup"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "cn"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "objectClass"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "structuralObjectClass"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "entryUUID"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "creatorsName"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "createTimestamp"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "gidNumber"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: oc_check_allowed type "member"
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: Entry (cn=test,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=org), attribute 'member' not allowed
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: entry failed schema check: attribute 'member' not allowed
May 22 13:48:12 intranet slapd[90208]: hdb_modify: modify failed (65)
```

I loaded the folowing schema files

```
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/cosine.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/nis.schema
include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/inetorgperson.schema
#include         /usr/local/etc/openldap/schema/openldap.schema
```

Installed via pkg_ng

```
# pkg info openldap-server
openldap-server-2.4.39_1
Name           : openldap-server
Version        : 2.4.39_1
Installed on   : Mon May 19 16:48:33 CEST 2014
...

# uname -a
FreeBSD intranet 10.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.0-RELEASE #0 r260789: Thu Jan 16 22:34:59 UTC 2014     root@snap.freebsd.org:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

EDIT:
OK, I figured out that I used posixGroup wrong. I should have used GroupOfNames, to insert a CN.

But what is the correct structure then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RFC2307 aka "NIS" schema does not allow `posixGroup` to have `member` attributes – only `memberUid`; you can see for yourself in the `nis.schema` file, around line 175.

```
objectClass: posixGroup         (structural)
cn: users
gidNumber: 1000
memberUid: daywalker
```

If you want to use `member` and entry DNs when creating "system" (POSIX) groups, you will need to use the [RFC2307bis](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-howard-rfc2307bis-02#section-5.2) schema, which changes `posixGroup` into auxiliary so that it could be used with either `groupOfNames` or `groupOfMembers` classes:

```
objectClass: groupOfMembers     (structural)
objectClass: posixGroup         (auxiliary)
cn: users
gidNumber: 1000
member: uid=daywalker,ou=people,dc=foo
```

For other purposes (LDAP-only groups), just `groupOfNames` or `groupOfMembers` should be enough.